# How to access my WP site locally and publicly?

Tags: customization

On my wordpress server I have a Q&A form set up on my local network, but it can only be accessed publicly, how can I access it from home.

- Wordpress server on local network
- WordPress Address (URL) brandon.raspctl.com
- Site Address (URL) brandon.raspctl.com
- I am able to connect to it away from home
- not able to connect to it at home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try accessing it using a direct IP address: Example: http://192.168.1.200/your_site_name

You may not even need the site name if it is the only site hosted from that server.

Ok in that case then you need to get the direct link from outside, replace the server URL with the IP address and bingo you should be there internally. The reason the link redirects you is because your WordPress settings use the  for its page direction in the permalinks and general areas.

Comment: when i type the ip address of the server it takes me to the site, but when i click on a link it takes me to brandon.raspctl.com/page-name and for some reson i cant accses my site via my public ip at home

Comment: @Austinthemighty I updated my answer to help you further.